# Using Silverlight controls from an WP7 XNA project

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I have an XNA project on WP7. I would like to get access to the camera raw data using the PhotoCamera class. I guess the only way to get it is using a Silverlight control called VideoBrush. Is there any way to use it without creating an xna-silverlight hybrid project?

I don't want to use the Silvelright's screen navigation system.

I tried to programmatically create a PhotoCamera, VideoBrush and UIElementRenderer classes, the problem is that when I make a new UIElementRenderer I get a NullReferenceException error. I do the following:

```
UIElementRenderer slRender;
Grid element;

element = new Grid();

slRender = new UIElementRenderer(element, 800, 480);
```

Any idea on how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this "Camera stream in XNA" : http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/88451/530446.aspx

Comment: well, that's more about using XNA from Silverlight, and the SLARToolkit is for silverlight apps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the Silverlight interop layer to access the live camera feed. XNA doesn't support it directly.